# MS Visio 2016 - Implementing A Standard Template Across the Agency

Tags: templates, visio

We have multiple locations and users that will soon be upgraded to Visio 2016. Visio is the tool that everyone will use for creating pre-incident plans. This means they all need to use standard shapes required by NFPA.

Is there a way to push a template/stencil to all users to ensure compliance?
(IE-During the upgrade or initial install?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, custom stencils are just files. Using a [Group Policy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/65f67962-582a-4af1-854d-8fd5e8888a04/how-to-send-a-file-to-other-computers-via-group-policy?forum=winserverGP) or a [login script](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/c607b501-0cb0-4eb8-830a-641de76488bc/copy-a-file-from-share-to-local-filesystem?forum=winserverGP), you could copy them to the user's My Shapes folder. See [*Import downloaded stencils* in the office docs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-downloaded-stencils-74bbdce1-4872-4d5b-af4c-e93fa23f7008)

> save the file to your My Shapes folder, which is located inside your default Documents folder (My Documents or Documents, depending on your version of Windows).

You can also overwrite an existing template or create a new template where these stencils are used. See [*Add a stencil to a template in Visio*](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-stencil-to-a-template-in-visio-8f27d068-d236-404d-8244-6f81c4d0b80b) in the Office docs.